# how to do stratification within group_by in r

Tags: r

I want to run stratification function with categories of group_by variable, but it seems the function ignore the groups. I think the reason is that once I use pull function, it ignored the group by variable. But if I don't use the pull function, the stratify doesn't know that I want to do it on the variable areavariable. How can I fix it? thanks.

```
stratify <- function(x, strata, breaks) {
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE, breaks = breaks)
  g <- length(h$counts)
  z <- data.frame(
    lower = rep(NA, g),
    upper = rep(NA, g),
    freq = h$counts,
    sqrtf = sqrt(h$counts),
    csqrtf = cumsum(sqrt(h$counts)),
    stratum = NA)
  k <- 1:(strata - 1) * max(z$csqrtf)/strata
  sizebound<-rep(NA, strata - 1)
  for (i in 1:g) {
    z$lower[i] <- h$breaks[i]
    z$upper[i] <- h$breaks[i + 1]
  }
  for (i in 1:(strata - 1)) {
    tmp <- which(abs(z$csqrtf - k[i]) == min(abs(z$csqrtf - k[i])))
    z$stratum[c(1:g) <= tmp & is.na(z$stratum)] <- i
    sizebound[i]<-z$upper[c(1:g) == tmp]
  }
  z$stratum[is.na(z$stratum)] <- strata
  out1 <-list(z, sizebound)
  return(out1)
}

strata_num <- 3 #USER INPUT
stratvar="areavariable" ##User Inputs

Stratum<-type_area2  %>%  filter(Outlier_for_area==0  ) %>% group_by(licence_type) %>% 
  pull(!!as.symbol(stratvar)) %>%  stratify(strata=strata_num, breaks=25)
Stratum
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please share a dataset as part of your code  or tweak your code to use one of the datasets that ship with R?

Comment: not an answer but just an aesthetic remark `pull(!!as.symbol(stratvar))`==`pull(stratvar)`

Comment: Also instead of `max(z$csqrtf)`==`z$csqrtf[nrow(z)]` and always use vectorised assignment  instead of loops ie : `lower = h$breaks[1:g], upper= h$breaks[1:(g+1)]`